# Library like Blockly for C++

Tags: open-source, library, c++, game-development, code-generation

I’m developing a visual programing tool for games, it has in place the UI which is similar to Unreal Engine’s Blueprint system.

Now I want to find a library to generate C++ source code from the graph. For instance Blockly has code generators for different dynamically typed languages. I’m particularly interested in C++ because it can be compiled to native machine code, or to other popular languages like JavaScript, Lua or C# (I guess Java too, but there is the NDK).

The library should be free and open source, and should have a permissive license (no viral, BSD like). Also having a supporting and active community could help too.

Comment: You are defining your own graphical language?  Presumably it is new and different than others? Why would you believe there is an available set of code (open source or not) that would know how to generate code from your particular type of graph honoring your particular semantics?

Comment: @IraBaxter my tool would have to spit out an abstract syntax tree in the syntax required by the generator.

Comment: If your tool can translate your graph to C++ ASTs, why can't it translate your graph to C++ source code fragments?  All the work is in the translation from your language to C++ (in whatever form), so what do you think you'd get by using a C++ AST?   [I have a tool that can do that, just don't see the point in your case]